# Self checking testbench in VHDL: what values should be tested?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I want to write a self checking testbench in VHDL for my design. I'm confused on which values to test. Should I check all possible values and see if they are correct? My design also contains a generic parameter, so I should also test different bit sizes. Testing all possible values becomes impossible for larger bit sizes. For example: how would people test a 64 bit floating point adder? I'm sure that it is physically impossible to test all values then?

Comment: This question requires approximately a book to answer it. Something like https://www.amazon.co.uk/Writing-Testbenches-Functional-Verification-Models/dp/1402074018/ref=sr_1_3 You might also look at http://www.osvvm.org

Comment: You should have a look at OSVVM just like @Brian-Drummond suggests. It will help you randomising your input data. To have a self-checking testbench with different values of the input generics you should also look at http://vunit.github.io which will help you with that. OSVVM is also included in the VUnit distribution.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors for VUNIT

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start with checking the outcome for some **specific inputs**.

If you can find out the expected values for **random numbers** in your testbench, you can use

> seeds

depending on the timestamp.

You should have some **check-function** which compares the output with the expected value.

I hope my suggestions are helpful.

Comment: You should use a seed value that is a function of something static, so that you can run the same random sequence again and again. If it's based on the time, then you could find a sequence that fails your test, then when you think you've fixed it, you can't run the same sequence again to check the fix.